# How can I make this LINQ to SQL where clause with conditions faster?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following LINQ to SQL query but I want to know if there is a faster way to validate data from a post action before adding them in a where clause? ex:

```
bookFilter = Informations coming from the post action

int count = from b in _libraryContext.Book
            join ba in _libraryContext.BookAuthor
            on b.Id equals ba.BookId
            where (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bookFilter.Name) ? 
            b.Name.Contains(bookFilter.Name.ToUpper()) : 1 == 1 )
            where (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bookFilter.Decription) ? 
            b.Description.Contains(bookFilter.Description.ToUpper()) : 1 == 1)
            where (bookFilter.BookId > 0 ? ba.BookId == bookFilter.BookId : 1 == 1)

return count;
```

Comment: What is your definition of "better" in this particular context?

Comment: let say cleaner and faster way ?

Comment: "Clean" is subjective and can be opinion based.  However if you're talking about performance that can be objectively measured and you should update your question to specify that's what you want.

Comment: @Zer0 i updated the title based on your comment. Thanks

Comment: @Kivo such catch-all queries are a bad practice in SQL. They aren't needed at all in LINQ though, because you can chain `.Where()` calls as needed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i want to keep my sql to linq approach since its cleaner and close to the sql syntax

Comment: @Kivo no it's not. It's a bug resulting in bad execution plans

Comment: @Kivo this article on [catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) explain the problems with your current approach - never mind the hard-to-read code. You have a 50% chance of creating a bad execution plan

Comment: @Kivo to avoid this you *must* use the `WITH RECOMPILE` hint, to force SQL Server to recompile the catch-all query on every single execution. Thus losing the benefit of execution plan caching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used this type of syntax much so I'm sure if you can do it this way, but you can certainly do it with LINQ and build up your query step by step like so:

```
var query = _libraryContext.Set<Book>();

if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bookFilter.Name))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(bookFilter.Name.ToUpper()));
}

if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bookFilter.Description))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Description.Contains(bookFilter.Description.ToUpper()));
}

if(bookFilter.BookId > 0)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.BookId == bookFilter.Id);
}

return query.Count();
```

Note: I have omitted the JOIN here as it seems unnecessary, but you can of course do the join in this syntax too if you need it.

Comment: i'm looking for a Linq to SQL approach and not a lambda approach

Comment: @Kivo LINQ is lambdas and the original attempt is a *bad practice that shouldn't be used* and *requires compilation hints to avoid performance issues*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos joins are generally much simpler in query expressions.With lambdas expression is hell and hard to debug and read

Comment: @Kivo that's not what the query is about though. Nothing forces you to use only one or the other form. All queries are `IQueryable` and return `IQueryable`. You can start with the joins in query form and add `.Where()` calls as needed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's a good idea indeed ! thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have accepted the solution that @Akinzekeel provided above. However, in the case that you are trying to use a single LINQ query, I would go for the solution below:

```
bookFilter = Informations coming from the post action
```

Please note here **`bookFilter`** has to be IQueryable!

```
int count = from b in _libraryContext.Book
            join ba in _libraryContext.BookAuthor
            on b.Id equals ba.BookId
            where (b.Name.Contains(bookFilter.Name.ToUpper()) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bookFilter.Name)) && 
            (b.Description.Contains(bookFilter.Description.ToUpper()) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bookFilter.Decription)) &&
            (ba.BookId == bookFilter.BookId || bookFilter.BookId == 0 )

return count;
```

If you trace the code above in SQL Profiler, you will see this will generate a single SQL query; something like `(OR IS NULL)` conditions.

Answer (score -3):

In SQL you could use COALESCE to default ignore parameters -- like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM book b
JOIN BookAuthor ba on b.id = ba.Bookid
WHERE COALESCE(UPPER(name), UPPER(b.name)) = UPPER(b.name)
  AND COALESCE(UPPER(description), UPPER(b.description)) = UPPER(b.description)
  AND COALESCE(bookid, b.book.id) = b.bookid
```

Recommended pattern is to put something like that in a SP and then call the SP.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because the question is about [LINQ to SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/), not SQL.

Comment: I'm going to take the reputation hit because I believe a significant number of people coming to this question will end up using this code to solve their problem.